# Unable to implement pullToRefrsh on Staggered GridView

Tags: android, gridview, pull-to-refresh

I want to implement pullToRefresh on staggered GridView. I have downloaded pullToRefresh library from GitHub. So I used PullToRefreshStaggeredGridView from that library.

But in my main project I am using latest support v4.jar file. I pullToRefresh library there is old support file. Due to this I am not able to implement pullToRefresh on my staggered gridview.

If I replace the latest support file in pullToRefresh library then I am getting error on this line

```
ScrollerCompat.from(context);
```

> This "from" method is undefined for type ScrollerCompact.

Please help me how can I fix this issue?